# Connect to TLS-enabled Elasticache Redis from Airflow Celery Executor

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, airflow, amazon-elasticache

I am currently using Celery Executor on Airflow 1.10. My broker is AWS Elasticache Redis (v. 5.0.6). How can I enable Encryption in-transit?

According to Airflow source code, `ssl_keyfile`, `ssl_certfile` and `ssl_ca_certs` are required.

```
elif 'redis://' in broker_url:
    broker_use_ssl = {'ssl_keyfile': conf.get('celery', 'SSL_KEY'),
                      'ssl_certfile': conf.get('celery', 'SSL_CERT'),
                      'ssl_ca_certs': conf.get('celery', 'SSL_CACERT'),
                      'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED}
```

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.10/airflow/config_templates/default_celery.py#L68-L72

But Elasticache Redis does not provide those TLS certificate. The official document only explain a solution for redis-cli, which uses TLS tunneling by stunnel.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/in-transit-encryption.html#connect-tls

Does Airflow Celery Executor support Encryption in-transit on Elasticache Redis? If so, how can we implement it?

Answer (score 0):

The following airflow config works with elasticache and redis ssl
note the extra `s` on the `rediss`

```
broker_url = rediss://:password@host:port/db?ssl_cert_reqs=required
broker_use_ssl = { "ssl_cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_REQUIRED }
```

```
ssl_active = False
ssl_key =
ssl_cert =
ssl_cacert =
```

Comment: Thanks. It might work but does not prevent man-in-the-middle attack.